# svg width css animation from left to right instead right to left

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to make the green boxes behave like the red ones but in opposite direction? The width should shrink from left to right and not right to left. I know its possible if i replace the boxes with div's and give those a background color, but it tried it and it just doesnt look as good. Also the hover is not doing what it should do, cant seem to fix that either.

https://jsfiddle.net/v72tjcae/

```
.block rect{
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

.block:hover rect{
    width: 0px;
}


<svg class="emblem" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px"
   height="500px" viewBox="0 0 553 553" enable-background="new 0 0 553 553" 
xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2">
  <g class="block">
    <rect x="277" y="126" fill="#960B2C" width="156" height="88"/>
    <rect x="120" y="126" fill="#004D44" width="157" height="88"/>
  </g>
  <g class="block">
    <rect x="277" y="232" fill="#960B2C" width="156" height="88"/>
    <rect x="120" y="232" fill="#004D44" width="157" height="88"/>
  </g>
  <g class="block">
    <rect x="277" y="339" fill="#960B2C" width="156" height="88"/>
    <rect x="120" y="339" fill="#004D44" width="157" height="88"/>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are aware that this only works on Chrome?

Comment: Oh damn you are right, but still. You think its possible in chrome?

Comment: Sure, animate the x down and the width up.